# How to fix POST method not sent

Tags: php, post, methods

Ok ! When i try the code  `"<p>  <?php echo $_POST['pseudo'] ?> </p>"` on the register page witch come before this one : i aint got my php pseudo showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mantra</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">


    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include('function.php'); ?>
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
    <style>

      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 90%;
        width:100%;
      }
      #button_go{
        margin:auto;
      }
      .Profile_picture{
        position: relative;
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: ;
        bottom:45px;
      }

      .container{
        margin-top: -42px;
        margin-bottom: ;
      }
      .cube_droite{
        position: absolute ;
        text-align: center;
        right: 50px ;
        width:300px;
        height: 350px;
        top: 630px;
        background-color: #a9c1c5;
      }
      select{
        background-color: #00cc66;
      }

      #link_validation{
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>



      <!-- Rectangle d'annotations d'information -->

    <div class="cube_droite">
      <!-- Photo de profil -->
      <img width="550px" height="150px" src="img/profile.jpg" alt="Profile_picture" class="Profile_picture">


      <!-- Call the php database register information -->

      <div class="container">
          </br>
          <div id="link_localisation">

         <button type="button" name="button" onclick="get_pos()">Geolocalise me !</button>  </div>

            <?php echo  $_POST['pseudo']  ?>



          </br>
            <label>Say more about yourself: <input id="personal_information"  type="text" ></input></label>
            <label>Ou travaillez vous ?
            <input type="text" id="position_lat" placeholder="Latitude"> </input>
            <input type="text" id="position_lng" placeholder="Longitude">  </input>
        </br>    ou</br>

            <input type="text" id="position_ville" placeholder="Ville">  </input>
        <div id="link_validation">

       <button type="button" name="button" onclick="get_pos()">valide</button>  </div>
            </label>
</div>
</div>

          <div id="map">  </div>




          <script>


          var map;

          var contentString = 'Montreal';


          function get_pos(){


              let coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(document.getElementById("position_lat").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("position_lng").value))

              // The marker, positioner
              let marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: coordinate, map: map});

              console.log(coordinate)

              console.log(parseFloat(document.getElementById("position_lat").value))}



















              // Initialize and add the map
              function initMap() {
                // The location of Uluru
              var uluru = {lng: -73.460472, lat:45.476861};
                // The map, centered at Uluru
              map = new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});

                    console.log(map)
              }

















          </script>
          <!--Load the API from the specified URL
          * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
          * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
          * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
          -->
          <script async defer
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCCbPf2erpAkX_VgYx4xGtrf_olrxDsvKY&callback=initMap">
          </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help please ?

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Try putting your submit button inside your form element. (Before </form>.)

Comment: Tryied, not working

Answer (score 0):

Is the file of the content with `"<p>  <?php echo $_POST['pseudo'] ?> </p>"` the same as the index.php?

Your submit button has to be in the  elements

Everything is in index.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    echo "My Name is: ". $_POST['pseudo']. "<br><br>";
}
?>

<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
  <label>Nom:
      <input type="text" name="pseudo" value="">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: They are both in the same file; i tryied mooving my submit into the <form> still doesnt work

Comment: Can you send us the complete code of the file? Or more code including the file names

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it out

Comment: i edit the page, add some code, if that doesnt work i'll try for a full picture of it.

Comment: Alright this doesnt work for me, i only got "; } ?>  displayed on my index screen. weird

Comment: Which PHP version do you use? Can you insert the three lines at the top of your file and execute it again? Send us the message which appears:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: im stuck adding this line, this doesnt show me any error and im not able to give you the code on CodePen

Comment: This is working now !

Comment: Good, so please mark the question as solved. Happy programming!